# .net validation of pdfa file

Tags: vb.net, itext, pdfa

I try to write a validation method in a VB project to check if a PDF file is PDF/A. I was playing with itextsharp.pdfa but i don't find a way to validate this.

From 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977379/how-can-i-test-a-pdf-document-if-it-is-pdf-a-compliant-with-itextsharp)
I understood that using itextsharp was not possible. Does itextsharp 5.5.5 include some functionalities like this?

Are there other dll I can use in a vb.net project for this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no such thing, but the European Union has mandated a project to build a "PDF/A Conformance Checker" as an open source project. You can follow the progress here: http://www.preforma-project.eu/pdfa-conformance-checker.html

Checking for PDF/A isn't trivial, so it will probably take a while before this project is finished. There has been a lot of discussion about this at the ISO meetings for PDF as well as by the PDF Association.

Answer (score 0):

VeraPdf has been released some time ago and can be integrated using [PdfAValidator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfAValidator/)

```
using (var pdfAValidator = new PdfAValidator.PdfAValidator())
     {
         var result = pdfAValidator.Validate(@"./TestPdfFiles/FromLibreOffice.pdf");
         Assert.True(result);
     }
```