# How to make the difference between PDF and PDF/A C#

Tags: c#, validation, pdfa

I developed a console based application which browses the same folder all midnights to converts PDF in PDF/A using ghostscript.

It actually works but now we get hundreds of files and I will need to check if each file is a PDF or a PDF/A to avoid launching the script in PDF/A files.

Is there any solution to make the difference between PDF and PDF/A ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you even try *anything*? You should at least show *some* affords, at least to avoid that you get answers that don´t help you much. Currently your question is far too broad and will make users here assume what you may or may not have tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, I was sick.

I found the solution for my problem using Pac0's solution.

Instead of using XML, I used iTextSharp.xmp like that :

```
public static bool CheckIfPdfa(PdfReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.Metadata != null && reader.Metadata.Length > 0)
        {
            IXmpMeta xmpMeta = XmpMetaParser.Parse(reader.Metadata, null);
            IXmpProperty pdfaidConformance = xmpMeta.GetProperty(XmpConst.NS_PDFA_ID, "pdfaid:conformance");
            IXmpProperty pdfaidPart = xmpMeta.GetProperty(XmpConst.NS_PDFA_ID, "pdfaid:part");
            reader.Close();

            if (pdfaidConformance == null || pdfaidPart == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like ITextSharp that will allow you to read PDF file.

To check if it is a PDF/A (well, actually to check if it claims to be a PDF/A, which should be sufficient for your needs) is a simple operation on reading PDF tags.

The code in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14070072/479251) should be what you need. It is VB.NET and it should be easy to translate to C# .

Basically :

- open the PDF with the reader from ITextSharp (or probably any pdf reading library)
- extract the XML metadata
- check for a XML tag named `pdfaid:conformance`, and see if its value is `A`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spire.PDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/) to detect the conformance level of a PDF document. Check out the following code:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
pdf.LoadFromFile("MS_Example.pdf");
PdfConformanceLevel conformance = pdf.Conformance;
Console.WriteLine(conformance.ToString());
```

Output:

[image]

Disclaimer：I'm an employee of Spire.

Comment: I tried the code but that not worked for me. Every PDF file that I test, I got none message

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a document claims to be compliant by examining the XMP Metadata of the document.

Using the Datalogics PDFL Library C# Interface:

```
using (var docInput = new Document("input.pdf"))
{
    bool bIsPdfA1a =  docInput.XMPMetadata.Contains("pdfaid:conformance=\"A\"");
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for Datalogics